# Is there a bus pass for Eastern Canada?

Tags: public-transport, canada, buses, quebec

A couple years ago, Greyhound discontinued the Discovery Pass that offered bus rides for a limited period on their North American network.

I also found about some [RoutPass](http://www.routpass.com/en/acc/index.php), a pass for riding on Quebec and Ontario buses for 7/14/21 days but apparently it is not valid any more since the end of 2012.

Is there a bus pass for (quasi) unlimited distance and time limited trips on buses in Eastern Canada? It would include Quebec and ideally the Maritimes (New Brunswick, Prince Edward Island and Nova Scotia) and even Ontario.

Comment: The bus situation is kind of chaotic in the eastern half of the country. Yes, there's Greyhound, but there are other providers to, from GO (Government of Ontario, focused on commuters but used by travelers to) to private and semi-private services you haven't heard of. Even if one company sold you a pass, you might find the towns you want to go to aren't covered by that company.

Comment: @KateGregory Yeah, if Orleans Express or Intercar or Maritime bus have a pass for either of them it would be already good. I find bus rides expensive there, but in particular I noticed their pricing is (base_fee + nb_km*kilometric_rate). So for example if I want to stop a full day in 10 towns in Gaspesie then I have to pay the base fee 10 times. What I am looking for is a pass that avoids that fee.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no pass at the moment. RoutPass disappeared after 2012. Since it was offered several bus companies in the network were taken over by multi-national transportation companies, services have since been, and continue to be, restructured and moved between operators especially in Quebec and the Maratimes.

At [Busbud](http://www.busbud.com) we're building a search engine covering several companies in the region, it might help you find who's currently operating and find the travel days with the lowest price.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Just to check, do you work at Busbud?

Comment: @Vince yep, thanks. Checked the policy & updated to disclose.

Answer (score 3):

One of our (Australia) local travel agents has [a page on Canadian bus passes](http://www.statravel.com.au/canada-bus-travel.htm), and it only lists western Canada as having them:

> With circuits in Western Canada (Vancouver side) and Eastern Canada
>   (Toronto side), Canada's  bus network has itineraries to suit just
>   about anyone’s needs. Passes in Western Canada have frequent
>   departures and all feature “jump on, jump off” flexibility.  **Eastern
>   Canada departures are not as frequent, so the departures are fixed
>   itinerary (no jump on/off).**

The [Moose Travel Network](http://www.moosenetwork.com/) is the same - listing hop on/off tours for western Canada but not eastern.